# Excel VBA - Copy and paste partial formatting

Tags: vba, excel, copy, paste

How can I copy and paste a cell from one cell to another that also carries-over formatting on certain texts within the cell using VBA in Excel? For example,

how would I copy "Hello *World*" so it exactly appears that way in pasted cell?

Thanks!

Comment: Select xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme when using the Range.PasteSpecial Method

Comment: Thanks! This is what i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Create macro and record your steps in Excel.Open the macro and view the VBA code

Answer (score 0):

***[Range.PasteSpecial Method (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839476.aspx)***

```
Option Explicit
Sub PasteSpecial()
    'Copy and PasteSpecial a Range
    Range("A1").copy
    Range("A3").PasteSpecial

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```